# JOIN tables ON DATE = NUMBER?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, numbers

I am trying to join two tables in Oracle SQL. One table has a DATE data type which represents a date(go figure) the other has an NUMBER data type which represents a month. I need to join the tables on the DATE's month and the NUMBER. I tried TO_CHAR() but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: tag your database, because the query is going to be depend on that. and what is the exact query that you tried and where it failed ?

Comment: please add the code on how did you tried TO_CHAR()

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's EXTRACT() function may do the trick ( https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm ).  Suppose we have 2 tables, populated with test data, like so:

```
create table numbers_ (num_ number);
create table dates_ (date_ date);

begin
  for i in 1 .. 12
  loop
    insert into numbers_ values (i);
  end loop;
  insert into dates_ values ('15-JUL-2017');
  insert into dates_ values ('16-AUG-2017');
  insert into dates_ values ('17-SEP-2017');
end;
/
```

We can use EXTRACT to get the "months" from the dates_ table:

```
select extract (month from date_) from dates_;

EXTRACT(MONTHFROMDATE_)
7
8
9
```

Use the "extracted" months for joining the tables:

```
select *
from 
  numbers_ N,
  ( select extract( month from date_ ) month from dates_ ) D
where N.num_ = D.month;

-- output
NUM_    MONTH
7       7
8       8
9       9
```

If you need more columns from the dates_ table, add them into the subquery (and to the main SELECT clause). Example:

```
select 
  N.num_
, D.date_
, D.month
from 
  numbers_ N,
  ( select 
      extract( month from date_ ) month 
    , date_
    from dates_ ) D
where N.num_ = D.month;
```

(See also: [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fbc5131a89e3d75d014d3564b54c9713))

Or - better (as @Wernfried Domscheit suggested):

```
select 
  N.num_
, D.date_
from 
  numbers_ N join dates_ D 
    on extract(month from D.date_) = N.num_ ;
```

Comment: You should prefer ANSI join syntax. And you can simplify like `... From numbers_ join dates_ on extract(month from date_) = num_`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: thanks for your feedback! I've added another query, using JOIN ... ON ...